# How to wait for the WildFly server to reload?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, application-server

I reload the WildFly server as follows

```
CliCommandBuilder cliCommandBuilder = ...
cliCommandBuilder
    .setCommand(
        "reload"
    );
Launcher.of(cliCommandBuilder)
    .inherit()
    .setRedirectErrorStream(true)
    .launch();
```

And I need to wait for the server to start, because then I will deploy the new content. How can I do this?

I tried use method `.waitFor()` from `java.lang.Process`

```
Launcher.of(cliCommandBuilder)
    .inherit()
    .setRedirectErrorStream(true)
    .launch().waitFor();
```

But the thread continues to work after shutting down WildFly, not starting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought the `reload` command waited to terminate the process until WildFly was reloaded. However, there is a [helper API](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-maven-plugin/tree/main/core) you could use to check the process. Something like this should work:

```java
final CliCommandBuilder commandBuilder = CliCommandBuilder.of("/opt/wildfly-27.0.0.Final")
        .setConnection("localhost:9990")
        .setCommand("reload");
final Process process = Launcher.of(commandBuilder)
        .inherit()
        .setRedirectErrorStream(true)
        .launch();

// Wait for the process to end
if (!process.waitFor(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
    throw new RuntimeException("The CLI process failed to terminate");
}

try (ModelControllerClient client = ModelControllerClient.Factory.create("localhost", 9990)) {
    while (!ServerHelper.isStandaloneRunning(client)) {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(200L);
    }
    if (!Operations.isSuccessfulOutcome(result)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to check state: " + Operations.getFailureDescription(result).asString());
    }
    System.out.printf("Running Mode: %s%n", Operations.readResult(result).asString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly connect the CLI to the server. By default, this is `localhost:9990`, which you can access by adding `connect` to the CLI commands (see the [WildFly Admin Guide](https://docs.wildfly.org/27/Admin_Guide.html#running-the-cli)). Otherwise, you should use the [`setController` method](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core/blob/19.0.0.Final/launcher/src/main/java/org/wildfly/core/launcher/CliCommandBuilder.java#L233-L270).